# Occurrences of a substring in a string without using string functions

Tags: java, string

I want to know how to count the occurrences of a particular sub-string in a string without using any of the built in JAVA string functions. For example:

```
InputString = "knowbutuknow"
subString = "know"
```

The program should return the result as 2.

EDIT: Re-phrased my question. This is one of those interview questions I came across.

EDIT: Basic string functions like charAt and length can be used here.

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible. How do you think the built-in methods are implemented ? :)

Comment: Ya...I should've re-phrased my question...what could be the logic for this? Any pointers?

Comment: The question is: Why do you want to avoid string functions? If you tell us what exactly you want to achieve we can help you much better.

Comment: are you allowed to convert the string to char array?

Comment: @KorayTugay you wouldn't need that -- charAt is sufficient, but it's not clear if that counts as a string method

Comment: charAt can be used as it's impossible to do this without using even that. I just want the approach that can be followed here. Can something on the lines of the KMP algorithm be followed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you already know the keyword you are searching for:

- Start at char "0" of Input String
- Iterate until "length - keyWordLength" (keyword of length 4 can not match into the last 3 chars)
- Inside: Iterate from 0 to keyWord.length -1 and always compare:
- Char at Position of outer loop PLUS position of inner loop of the Input string with the char at "inner loops" position of the keyword.
- if you find a match, go ahead with the innerloop, if it does not match, advance the outer loop, by simple "breaking" the inner loop.
- If you have a match, and completely processed the inner loop, you have a match of that keyword.

Something like this. I'm Assuming `String.length` to be allowed. Otherwhise you would need to create your own strlen function. (This can be achieved, using a `forach` loop and simple counting "up")

This is untested and may not work out of the box, but should give you a brief idea.

```
String inputString = "knowbutuknow";
String subString = "know";

int matches = 0;
for (int outer = 0; outer <= inputString.length() - subString.length(); outer++){
  for (int inner = 0; inner < subString.length(); inner++){
    if (inputString.charAt(outer + inner) == subString.charAt(inner)){
      // letter matched, proceed.
      if (inner == subString.length()-1){
        //last letter matched, so a word match at position "outer"
        matches++;
        //proceed with outer. Room for improvement: Skip next n chars beeing
        // part of the match already.
        break;
      } 
    }else{
      //no match for "outer" position, proceed to next char.
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

edit: Sorry, mixed in some php :) fixed it.

Comment: This is actually what I'm looking for. Thank you for answering the question. I should've been more clear in my question. I would be more careful the next time.

Comment: @RTG87 maybe you should add a check before starting, `if (subString.length() <= inputString.length())` to avoid unwanted results.

Comment: Yes. I'm taking care of all the edge cases. Thank you!